# Why is my Merge Sort not saving the sorted arrays?

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I realize i'm not returning my tempPoints to anything but what can I do to fix this?

Right now it sorts correctly, but when it sorts the next tier of halves they remain unsorted.

UNSORTED POINTS:

(-2, -42)
(-15, 2)
(32, 8)
(-26, 21)
(39, -42)
(-40, -18)
(-30, 7)
(-12, -28)
(19, -16)
(-16, -38)

SORTED POINTS :

(-2, -42)
(-15, 2)
(32, 8)
(-26, 21)
(39, -42)
(-40, -18)
(-30, 7)
(-12, -28)
(19, -16)
(-16, -38)

If i step through my program using the debugger, I can see it sorting each partition correctly but it doesn't carry over to the next merge.

```
private void mergeSortRec(Point[] pts)
{
    int middle = pts.length / 2;


    if( pts.length ==1)
    {
        return;
    }

    Point[] left = new Point[middle];
    Point[] right = new Point[pts.length - middle];


    for(int i = 0; i < middle; i++)
        left[i] = pts[i];

    for( int j = 0; j < pts.length - middle; j++ )
        right[j] = pts[middle+j];

    mergeSortRec(left);
    mergeSortRec(right);

    merge(left, right);
}

private Point[] merge(Point[] left, Point[] right)
{
    int x = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    Point[] tempPoints = new Point[(left.length) + (right.length)];

    while( i < left.length || j < right.length )
    {
        if( i < left.length && j < right.length)
        {   
            if( pointComparator.compare(left[i], right[j]) == -1 )
            {
                tempPoints[x] = left[i];
                x++;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                tempPoints[x] = right[j];
                x++;
                j++;
            }
        }
        else if (i == left.length)
        {
            tempPoints[x] = right[j];
            x++;
            j++;
        }
        else if( j == right.length)
        {
            tempPoints[x] = left[i];
            x++;
            i++;
        }

    }

    return tempPoints;
}
```

Comment: Because you don't do anything with the return value of `merge`? (Note that you should be merging them back into the original array)

Comment: Ok so at the end of my merge. I copied over tempPoints to the array stored in my object, but the index is set to 0  at the start of every merge. What do I do to keep the sorted index? I removed my return and changed the method to void. Just saw other comments

Answer (score 0):

In mergeSortRec you aren't returning anything.

The left and right arrays get sorted and merged, but then fall out of scope. Try changing your code to return the merge result.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything with the result of `merge`, so the merged array is simply discarded. Moreover, you need to merge back into the original array.

Change your `merge` array to take the array you want to merge into as a parameter:

```
private void merge(Point[] left, Point[] right, Point[] pts)
```

and use `pts` instead of `tempPoints`; call like:

```
merge(left, right, pts);
```

since `pts` is the array you want to update, and is the correct length.

Comment: Thanks. I went back and changed all 'pts' and 'tempPoints' to the objects array. Finally worked and I learned.